# onEdit function is not running on google sheets

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet for **Data Entry**, I created some funtions to **Search, Save, Update** and **Delete** data.

till yesterday I called Spreadsheet by ActiveSpreadsheet(), it's worked well ..

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

but today I called the spreadsheet by openById(), and then **onEdit** is not triggering when data edited..

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1F3Fh7wx8S78IvQWuB-3NiByjY-EQ_hGnlX-v4hI94hM");
```

If anyone know what went wrong, pls help ..

Here is the Spreadsheet Link:
[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F3Fh7wx8S78IvQWuB-3NiByjY-EQ_hGnlX-v4hI94hM/edit#gid=0)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: `openById` requires authorization. Use installable triggers.

Comment: thank you master for the reply, can you change it to installble triggers for me.. because I dont know about them. thank you

Comment: really I dont know and not uderstand the answer for already questioned. pls can you modify my spreadsheet for installble triggers. thank you